# Error in Tikz text

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I am facing this error when I am using a tikz text Can you please tell me what is wrong ?

```
Package pgfkeys Error: The key '/tikz/text' requires a value. I
am going to ignore this key.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text            centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\tikzstyle{text} = [text width=0.5cm,text centered]


\title{Communication protocol}
\author{beltagymohamed }
\date{June 2015}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\newpage
%sadas

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Enter Command };
\node (okok) [decision, below of=done, yshift= -2.5cm] {Every thing is O.K.?};                    

% Connect okok yes to enter command 
\draw [arrow] (okok)-|   ([xshift=1.5cm]  okok.east) |-   (in1) ;
\node[text, below left of=okok,xshift= 3.6cm,yshift= 1.6cm] (okokyes) {Yes}; 


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The node names `start` and `done` are unknown and you can't redefine `text`. Use something like `mytext` instead.

Comment: @DanielSchlegel Thank you very much it worked as you advised :) :)
I wish you a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodes `start` and `done` are not defined, therefore I couldn't use them. The error with `text` is that you cannot redefine it, as @Daniel Schlegel pointed out.
If you change it to `Mytext` everything works fine.

I made small changes to your diagram, check if everything is as you want it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{Mytext} = [text width=0.5cm,text centered]

\title{Communication protocol}
\author{beltagymohamed }
\date{June 2015}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

%Nodes
\node (start) [startstop] {START};
\node (in1) [io, below =of start] {Enter Command };
\node (okok) [decision, below =of in1, yshift= -2.5cm] {Every thing is O.K.?};
\node (stop) [startstop,below = of okok] {STOP};

% Arrows
\draw[arrow] (start.south) to (in1.north);
\draw[arrow] (in1.south) to (okok.north);
\draw [arrow] (okok) -| node[Mytext,pos=0.1,above] (okokyes) {Yes}  ([xshift=1.5cm]  okok.east) |-   (in1) ;
\draw [arrow] (okok.south) -- node[Mytext,pos=0.1,right] (okokno) {No} (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it worked as you advised :) :)
I wish you a nice day :)  @MarcoG

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy You're welcome! :-)